# Create new lists looping through two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Using two different lists `A` and `B` trying to create new lists as follows:

1. Total number of new lists are equal to the total number of elements
   in list `B`.
2. Each new column contains the items which result from
   multiplying elements in list `A` against elements In list `B`

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [3, 4, 7] # list B has 3 elements, therefore 3 new lists are required
```

The lists would look like:

```
new_list1 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
new_list2 = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
new_list3 = [7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
```

With the following loop, I see that I am returning the right values but can't group into list/dictionary as above.

```
list_dict = {}
for j in B:
    for k in A:
        list_dict = k * j
        print(list_dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fancy one-liner:

```
C = [list(map(lambda x: x * b, A)) for b in B]
```

Translated to loops:

```
C = []
for b in B:
    new_list = []
    for a in A:
        new_list.append(b * a)
    C.append(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[
  [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
  [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], 
  [7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
]
```

Comment: The solution is correct. "C" should be lower case (to follow python style guides).  (And so should A & B from the question unless they are considered constants)

Comment: Your thoughtfulness to include the for loop version to help me better understand was necessary and fully appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you need to store the results to a list and store that list into the dict:

```
list_dict = {}
for j in B:
    list_ = []
    for k in A:
        list_.append(k * j)
    list_dict[j] = list_
```

Output:

```
{3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], 4: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], 7: [7, 14, 21, 28, 35]}
```

Or you could use a nested list comprehension:

```
new_list1, new_list2, new_list3 = [[a*b for a in A] for b in B]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [3, 4, 7]
for i in B:
    list=[]
    for j in A:
       list.append(i*j)
    print(list)
output:-
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?